# How to fix render ejs in node properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, ejs

I'm fetching data from mongodb and sending it through as `res.render('user', {data: result})`.
Now at *ejs* side I'm fetching this data field is a JSON object with name, email, password etc. field and array of attendance. Like this result:

```
{
    name:"Joe",
    password:"jdsj",
    attendance:[
        entry: Date,
        late: true/false
    ]
}
```

Now when I loop through this array like:

```
<% var counter = 0 %>
<% for( var i = 0; i< data.attendance.length/2; 
i+2{%>

    <% if(data.attendance.length===0){%>
        <% counter=0 %> 
        <% } else{ %>
        <%  counter++ %>
    <% } %>    
<% } %>`
```

When I fetch it on a page, it is not rendering. It is rendering ok without the *for* loop, but with looping its not rendering.

```
<li><%= data.name%></li>
<li><%= counter %></li>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append data in li element inside loop like this

```
 <ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= data.name %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats not the issue. Its when i put that for loop it wont render but when i remove that for loop it renders with all data